# CSS Valid But Not Applying Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

DISCLAIMER: I have searched this topic to no avail, this seems to be a Chrome only issue.

Safari for OSX and Firefox OSX work fine.

So I have some styles for an element which do not dynamically apply, i.e. on page load it works fine but as i use the page, it doesn't.

Here's a pen to demonstrate:
http://codepen.io/craig-wayne01/pen/xcIid

and the selector thats giving me the problem is this one

```
label.pagination:first-of-type,
     label.pagination:last-of-type,
     input.pagination[type=radio]:checked+label.pagination,
     input.pagination[type=radio]:checked+label.pagination+input[type=radio].pagination+label.pagination
```

So basically this is an example of a pagination footer area

and what im trying to achieve is simply changing the colour of the next number

so if i click on #4, #5 needs to change colour as well

which doesn't work.

Then pen is quite self explanatory. Additionally I can't fathom why this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

The only thing i can think of is that css does not work backwards, but i've used similar selectors in the past and i've had no issue.

Comment: It seems to be working?? When i click 4, 5 is getting selected as well...

Comment: You might want to update the question mentioning that...

Comment: Is it an issue that you are mixing `input[type=radio].pagination` and `input.pagination[type=layout]`? Shouldn't matter, but...

Comment: It breaks in Chrome under Linux too, so at least it's consistent...

Comment: @torazaburo, nope, css selectors are perfect. thanks though, this seems to be a bug in chrome, #confuzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience attempting something similar for a CSS only mobile menu, checking or focusing elements doesn't force a redraw for sibling elements. I had this trouble on the iPad.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i just assumed css would be able to handle this... more worrying is that its a chrome only issue. ive always held chrome in high regard